# Warum lachst du über meinen Freund?

Tags: usage

Can `lachen über` be used only to mean *laughing at something?* Or can it be used when laughing at a person or situation as well?

Comment: Refering to the title of your question, IMO the meaning of _Warum lachst Du über meinen Freund?_ depends on the situation and emphasis. It could be understood as _question for the reason_ why someone is laughting as well as expression that the person _is upset with the fact that someone laughted_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean *lachen über* meaning 'mock', you use

> jemanden auslachen.

Then, your example would be

> Warum lachst du meinen Freund aus?

For situations *lachen über* is indeed appropriate:

E.g.:

> Der kleine Bub hat darüber gelacht, dass seine Schwester ins Wasser gefallen ist.